# Теряется стиль у родителя, при наведении на дочерний элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть меню, в одной из ячеек <li>  находится два элемента :

1. Ссылка, ведущая на отдельную страницу
2. Кнопка, открывающая выпадающее меню

По шаблону кнопка располагается справа. Обычно элемент <li> и являлся кнопкой для открытия выпадающего меню, но здесь  он независимый (ведёт на отдельную страницу), и я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при наведении на кнопку, у родителя теряется стиль при наведении.
Как сохранять стиль у родителя с помощью jQuery ?

Тут ещё такой нюанс : Когда кнопка была нажата и меню выпало, то у кнопки должен быть другой цвет (красный), если увести курсор с <li>, иначе она сливается с фоном. А при наведении на родителя - снова белый.

Мне предлагали добавление кода на нативном JS в сам HTML тег **<i>**, но это не практично, т.к. при необходимости изменить цвет, придётся лезть во все HTML страницы. Я пробовал с 'mouseover' и 'mouseout', но тогда цвет меняется у всего выпадающего меню.
Заранее спасибо за помощь
Вот ссылка на песочницу

https://jsfiddle.net/Logp8w5g/66/

```
div>
<div class="sidebar-menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About me</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Fashion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Beauty</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Wedding</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Tests</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Travel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Single Project</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Так же есть и другой шаблон, где показано три варианта цвета для кнопки: состояние покоя, наведение на <li> и наведение на кнопку. Картинки я прикреплю в песочнице. Есть ли способ, который поможет реализовать оба варианта ?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Додумался

```
$(function(){

  var chevron = $('.fa-chevron-down');
  var dropDown = $('.dropdown-menu');
  var drop = $('.dropdown > a');

  drop.on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).css({
      'background' : '#E50A0A',
      'color' : '#fff'
    });
    chevron.css({
      'color' : '#fff'
    });
  });
  drop.on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).css({
      'background' : '#fff',
      'color' : '#191919'
    });
    chevron.css({
      'color' : '#ccc'
    });
  });

  chevron.on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).css({
      'color' : '#fff'
    });
    $(this).prev('a').css({
      'background' : '#E50A0A',
      'color' : '#fff'
    });
  });
  chevron.on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).css({
      'color' : '#ccc'
    });
    $(this).prev('a').css({
      'background' : '#fff',
      'color' : '#191919'
    });
  });
```